# Get Python flask application running with wsgi and passenger

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, namecheap

Trying to get simple one file (+ passenger_wsgi) Python Flask app running at NameCheap.com.

passenger_wsgi.py:

```
import imp # I added this line (imp)
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
"""
# This is what the cPanel created by default:
# Commented out for now, see below this function
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    message = 'It works!\n'
    version = 'Python %s\n' % sys.version.split()[0]
    response = '\n'.join([message, version])
    return [response.encode()]
"""
# This is what I added:
wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'main.py')
application = wsgi.app
#app = wsgi.app
```

main.py:

```
import flask
appy = flask(__name__)
application = appy
@appy.route('/')
def main():
    return "<h1>Beginning03</h1>"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    appy.run(debug=True)
```

error log:

```
App 332651 output: File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
App 332651 output: appy = flask(__name__)
App 332651 output: TypeError
App 332651 output: 'module' object is not callable
```

Ideas? I imagine my problem comes from mis-use of "application" and "appy" objects.
Yeah, I'm fairly new to Python :-)

Comment: `from flask import Flask;
app = Flask(__name__)` You may use any other name than `app `.

Comment: Klaus thank you! Does this mean I need to change "appy" everywhere to "app"? FYI: Everywhere you see "appy" right now I had as "app" before with same error.

Comment: I see you edited your comment. Thank you! I want to be sure I understand. Are you saying I need to change appy = Flask(__name__) to "app = Flask..." but keep "appy" everywhere else?

Comment: Error: App 431852 output:     from flask import flask
App 431852 output: ImportError: cannot import name 'flask' from 'flask'

Comment: No, your import and the `Flask` have to be changed. But I **recommend* to stick with `app`  it is the typical name for a Flask application, You seem to have been unsure about the name.

Comment: Capitalization matters.

Comment: OMG it worked! THANK YOU!!!! The issue was capitalization of "Flask" vs "flask".